# This is a good connection for a decoupling cap on an IC?

Tags: pcb, decoupling-capacitor

Since I have no space on the BOT layer to place a cap near IC. I need to place a decoupling cap on the other side of the board, this is a good connection?[image]

Comment: Need some context. Positioning is more than whether or not it's on a via.

Comment: What is the capacitor value?

Comment: I'm skeptical that you can't fit the cap right where that massive via is placed.

Comment: I forgot to specify that cap is under the IC.

Answer (score 1):

If there is really no space, then you can place the capacitors on the other side of the board. First reference should be the datasheet of the IC. It is okay to place the caps in the other layer, provided the track length is still kept as short as possible (BGAs). Place the capacitor one end as close as possible to pin IC and the other end to directly to ground via a via (right?)

Comment: All bgas do not have their caps on the bottom, you can often make lower impedance connections by using the top layer.

Comment: @some Hmm yes. I shouldn't have told 'all'. Even in my board virtex FPGA has caps in its surrounding..like a terracotta army. :)

Comment: @Umar Ceramic soldiers protecting the FPGA- nice analogy, hopefully the FPGA has not passed into the afterlife.